# I built sms reading app but it starts but does not fetch the sms

Tags: java, android, android-broadcastreceiver

This is my main java file which i built for fetching sms using sms content provider and wants to show in my app.But for some reasons the app stars without any error but it show the messages on my phone. It shows all the buttons and list view and all is right but the sms content that it should show is no there.

```
package com.smsapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
 import android.widget.TextView;

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {

// GUI Widget
Button btnSent, btnInbox, btnDraft;
TextView lblMsg, lblNo;
ListView lvMsg;

// Cursor Adapter
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Init GUI Widget
    btnInbox = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnInbox);
    btnInbox.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnSent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSentBox);
    btnSent.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnDraft = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDraft);
    btnDraft.setOnClickListener(this);

    lvMsg = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMsg);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == btnInbox) {

        // Create Inbox box URI
        Uri inboxURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

        // List required columns
        String[] reqCols = new String[]{"_id", "address", "body"};

        // Get Content Resolver object, which will deal with Content
        // Provider
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

        // Fetch Inbox SMS Message from Built-in Content Provider
        Cursor c = cr.query(inboxURI, reqCols, null, null, null);

        // Attached Cursor with adapter and display in listview
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, c,
                new String[]{"body", "address"}, new int[]{
                R.id.lblMsg, R.id.lblNumber});
        lvMsg.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    if (v == btnSent) {

        // Create Sent box URI
        Uri sentURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");

        // List required columns
        String[] reqCols = new String[]{"_id", "address", "body"};

        // Get Content Resolver object, which will deal with Content
        // Provider
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

        // Fetch Sent SMS Message from Built-in Content Provider
        Cursor c = cr.query(sentURI, reqCols, null, null, null);

        // Attached Cursor with adapter and display in listview
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, c,
                new String[]{"body", "address"}, new int[]{
                R.id.lblMsg, R.id.lblNumber});
        lvMsg.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    if (v == btnDraft) {
        // Create Draft box URI
        Uri draftURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/draft");

        // List required columns
        String[] reqCols = new String[]{"_id", "address", "body"};

        // Get Content Resolver object, which will deal with Content
        // Provider
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

        // Fetch Sent SMS Message from Built-in Content Provider
        Cursor c = cr.query(draftURI, reqCols, null, null, null);

        // Attached Cursor with adapter and display in listview
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, c,
                new String[]{"body", "address"}, new int[]{
                R.id.lblMsg, R.id.lblNumber});
        lvMsg.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

   }
}
```

//    This is my First XML file activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnInbox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Inbox"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSentBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Sent Box"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDraft"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Draft"></Button>
</LinearLayout>

 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvMsg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"></ListView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

// this is my second XML  file row:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/lblMsg">                      </TextView>
<TextView android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#00f"
    android:id="@+id/lblNumber"></TextView>
```

Comment: The Constructor you are using for SimpleCursorAdapter is deprecated from API Level 11(HoneyComb). What is your targetsdkversion? more [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html)

Comment: Sir my target sdk version is 24